# How to change max size of request in SOAP?

Tags: php, soap

qiuck question - how to set max size of content-lenght in PHP SoapClient? My message is simply too long and I'm getting fatal error...

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Something like Uncaught SOAPClient exception and then [HTTP] Bad request. When I removed some rows in database in WCF request goes good. But in such amount of data SoapClient dosent even try to send it.

Comment: Show some code. Perhaps you give away the request to be handled BEFORE doing some extra trim and stuff, so the content-size doesn't match.